# unable to invoke firefox gecko driver 0.20.1 with selenium 3.0.1 & firefox version 61.0.1

Tags: selenium, firefox, driver, gecko

I am using framework and I am unable to invoke firefox gecko driver 0.20.1  with selenium 3.0.1 & firefox version 61.0.1. I want to know which gecko driver is compatible with selenium 3.0.1 & firefox version 61.0.1. i have tried all version of gecko driver from 0.16.1 till 0.21.1. But everytime it fail. My framework i correct as it is running in chrome.

Comment: You need to update the Selenium version.

Comment: I have done all my framework in Selenium 3.0.1. And so I don't want to make any changes. Is it possible to use some specific gecko driver version so that it can work. If I update selenium version my framework will fail.

Comment: Did you try? updating Selenium shouldn't cause any problems. I don't have the compatibility list, but if I remember correctly GeckoDriver v0.16.0 need selenium 3.4 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with firefox 61.0.1, I suggest you to upgrade the selenium. As per release notes of gecko driver v0.21.0 (latest version) **Firefox 57 (and greater)** & **Selenium 3.11 (and greater)** will work.

I am using gecko driver 0.21.0 with selenium 3.11 and able to work with FF 61.0.1

For detail compatibility of available versions of Gecko driver kindly refer the release note https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases Hope this helps..